# How to change Background color TabBar behind border radius with ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, typescript, react-native, mobile

I would change background color behind the TabBar with ReactNative like the image below.

[image]

My `App.tsx` code where I define the `NavigationContainer` and the `Tab.Navigator` :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import LocationScreen from './screens/LocationScreen';
import Root from './Root';
import Assets from './assets/Assets';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarActiveTintColor: Assets.colors.gold,
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: Assets.colors.softBlack,
            borderTopWidth: 0,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
            borderTopRightRadius: 15,
          },
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Root"
          component={Root}
          options={{title: 'Accueil', headerShown: false}}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Location"
          component={LocationScreen}
          options={{title: 'Emplacements', headerShown: false}}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your could try

```
tabBarStyle: {
    borderTopWidth: 0,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
    borderTopRightRadius: 15,
},

tabBarContainerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: Assets.colors.softBlack,
},
```

Comment: Hello, thank's for your answer but it didn't work. `Tab.Navigator.screenOptions` don't contain `tabBarContainerStyle`. Also, I use React Native 0.71 and React Navigation 6.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to resolve this issu.
I have just add `position: 'absolute'` to my `tabBarStyle`.

The next code work's perfectly :

```js
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarShowLabel: false,
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: Assets.colors.softBlack,
            borderTopWidth: 0,
            borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
            borderTopRightRadius: 15,
            position: 'absolute',
          },
        }}>
```

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone have the same goal, but realize content of the page does not shows properly, this is how to do it without the option "position absolute"

give it a paddingTop -40 like

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: SAPS_THEME['headline-txt']
    },
    headerStyle: {
      backgroundColor: SAPS_THEME['main-bg']
    },
    tabBarStyle: {
      backgroundColor: SAPS_THEME['main-bg-opacity-7'],
      borderWidth: 0,
      borderTopEndRadius: 20,
      borderTopStartRadius: 20,
      borderTopWidth: 0,
      paddingTop: 6,
      backfaceVisibility: false,
      marginTop: -40 // <-- this one
    },
    tabBarBackground: null,
    tabBarActiveTintColor: SAPS_THEME.highlight
  }}
>
```